# Why a Uniswap/PancakeSwap emits same event multiple times

Tags: uniswap, events, pancakeswap, uniswapv3, swaps

does someone know why Uniswap/PancakeSwap pairs occasionally emit the same Swap event multiple times?
There is it an example on dexscreener on WBNB/USDT:
I happen to also catch it in my script that I was using to practice, I got that transaction 0xe294501387641c2c5fcee6a4d5e887111c1abc5e842b633917830e0866aecd4a 5 times received by my script.

[image]

Comment: The transaction doesn't exists. In general contracts can do anything they want to do, like emitting multiple events. I've seen that happens with rebalancing tokens.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks, but what do you mean? the transaction is there in bscscan

Comment: You said Uniswap so I thought it was an Ethereum transaction.

Comment: In the particular case of the indicated transaction. Pancakeswap is called several times by another contract. Without the source is complicated to analyze the reason to perform multiple swaps of the same tokens.

Comment: @Ismael it is actually not multiple swaps, it is just one swap but for some reason it got complicated and multiple back and forth occurred with same amount (0.06991 WBNB -> 17.13$)

Comment: Using tenderly it shows multiple calls to PancakeRouter from `0x3f14c8960100c5943bdec17b3e7a9169fe6d7344`. Another contract without source code verified.